# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2} - \frac{n\pi}{4}\right) = \sqrt{2^n}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, fourier-series

While working on a separate problem, I stumbled upon a beautiful fact that I simply couldn't prove.. I suspect it requires some tools/tactics I've not encountered yet. The statement is the following:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2} - \frac{n\pi}{4}\right) = \sqrt{2^n}$$

From my humble experience, I've got two suspicions for a successful approach:

- Complex number manipulation and working with the real part;
- Some kind of Fourier transform... this really just reminds me of it.

I couldn't come up with anything nice using complex numbers and I'm not that familiar with Fourier transforms yet, so I don't have the right intuition there.

Furthermore, this sum is just begging to employ Newton's binomial at some point, but I couldn't transform it to a form where it is applicable.

Any advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!

P. S. I don't opt for induction proofs, I'm rather interested in evaluating the sum on the LHS and arriving at the RHS.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1696850p10881414. Somehow it follows from the binomial theorem.

Comment: @player3236 That was the right thing, thank you a lot! How do you, people, manage to find such things when needed! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first idea is correct.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}2-\frac{n\pi}4\right)&=
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \Re\left(\exp\left(\frac{k\pi i}2-\frac{n\pi i}4\right)\right)\\
&=\Re\left(\left(e^{-n\pi i/4}\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \left(e^{\pi i/2}\right)^k\right)\\
&=\Re\left(\left(e^{-n\pi i/4}\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk i^k\right)\\
&=\Re\left(\left(e^{-n\pi i/4}\right)(1+i)^n\right)\\
&=\Re\left(\left(e^{-n\pi i/4}\right)\left(\sqrt2e^{\pi i/4}\right)^n\right)\\
&=\sqrt{2^n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I was just coming back from AoPS to write the very same thing I was finally able to figure out for myself. Thank you for the confirmation nonetheless, you've done the heavy lifting brilliantly! That's just beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

*This answer adapted from the AoPS link in comments*
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\cos(k\pi/2-n\pi/4)$$
$$=\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(\cos(k\pi/2-n\pi/4)+i\sin(k\pi/2-n\pi/4))\right)$$
$$=\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nke^{i(k\pi/2-n\pi/4)}\right)$$
$$=\operatorname{Re}\left(e^{-in\pi/4}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk i^k\right)$$
$$=\operatorname{Re}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2(1+i)\right)^{-n}(1+i)^n\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^{-n}=2^{n/2}$$

Comment: That's a nice alternative in terms of the calculations, of course! Thank you, too, but unfortunately I can only accept one answer.